# Displaying media metadata using Exoplayer MediaSessionConnector using car media app

Tags: exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, android-mediasession, android-automotive, mediasession

My media app using Exoplayer's mediasessionconnector to send the mediasession metadata to the Car media App. Car media app supposed to show the title, album and artist of the current track.
But it just shows the title with album and artist left blank.

The problem is TimelineQueueNavigator uses MediaDescriptionCompat which takes title and descriptions. There is no explicitly way to set artist and album. How to hanlde this situation?

Answer (score 0):

As per DefalutMetadataProvider Album and Artists needs to be bundled in MediaDescriptionCompat. Then it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).